# JWT Failing Authorization

Tags: c#, .net, jwt, maui

I am implementing JWT to authenticate an API controller in a .NET 7 project. The endpoint is decorated with an `[Authorize]` attribute and the solution also uses cookie authentication to validate web users.

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        IConfigurationSection jwtsettings = Configuration.GetSection("JWTSettings");

        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {

            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = jwtsettings["Issuer"],
            ValidAudience = jwtsettings["Audience"],
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtsettings["SecretKey"]))
        };
    })
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
    });
```

When the user logins through the login method it generates a JWT

**Generate JSONWebToken**

```
 private string GenerateJSONWebToken(string email, string userid)
 {
     var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_jwt.Value.SecretKey));
     var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

     var claims = new[] {
         new Claim("UserId", userid),
         new Claim("EmailAddress", email),
         new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
     };

     var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_jwt.Value.Issuer,
         _jwt.Value.Audience,
         claims,
         expires: DateTime.Now.AddYears(30),
         signingCredentials: credentials);

     return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
 }
```

I then store this token as a string in my MAUI app (In Preferences at the moment).

Inside the MAUI app, I construct a RestSharp call to Get a resource.

**MAUI RestSharp call**

```
var token = Preferences.Default.Get("Token", "n/a");

var client = new RestClient(_settingsService.GetSettings().Result.APIURL);

client.AddDefaultHeader("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", token));

var request = new RestRequest("mobile/myteams");

var execute = client.Execute(request);
```

This returns Not Authorized when I execute it.

When I make the same two requests into Request Bin, i can see the call from the MAUI app/RestSharp has an altered signature portion which I believe might be the issue, but I don't know where to go from here.

**The token as it appeared in Requestbin from postman, which matches whats in Preferences**

```
eyJhbGciO****6IkpXVCJ9.eyJVc2VySWQiOiJkZDVhYTY3My02YzdmLTQ4MzctODQ2My1jZGVmZjVlMGJkN2QiLCJFbWFpbEFkZHJlc3MiOiJtYXR0eXdhcnJAbWUuY29tIiwianRpIjoiZGFiMjQxMjAtZTYwMC00ZTFkLThmMzEtOTU3M2Q5ZTA5MjQ2IiwiZXhwIjoyNjQ5MjM4NTY4LCJpc3MiOiJSYWNrRW1BcHAiLCJhdWQiOiJSYWNrRW1BcHBNb2JpbGVBUEkifQ.OpEWF1Nkda__xUmET2tOh2wuLYJiTvAY4oG1Nyo7YPw
```

**The token as it appared in Requestbin from the Maui app/Restsharp which has a different signature**

```
eyJhbGciO****6IkpXVCJ9.eyJVc2VySWQiOiJkZDVhYTY3My02YzdmLTQ4MzctODQ2My1jZGVmZjVlMGJkN2QiLCJFbWFpbEFkZHJlc3MiOiJtYXR0eXdhcnJAbWUuY29tIiwianRpIjoiNmM4ODllZGQtZGJiMC00NmQwLWI3MzEtNTkwMmY4NmU1MTQ3IiwiZXhwIjoyNjQ5MjM1NTMzLCJpc3MiOiJSYWNrRW1BcHAiLCJhdWQiOiJSYWNrRW1BcHBNb2JpbGVBUEkifQ.FD5PQcNKr0wa7maei361XKDIkljFWvoj4OkYYJ0xbU8
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: have you verified the value of the token when you first receive it, when you store it in Preferences, and when you retrieve it again?  Narrowing down exactly which step introduces the error would be helpful.

Comment: Putting a breakpoint in immdiately after storing it and immediately after recalling it from Preferences, the variables in VS that are reported are a match.

Comment: I found that I had a cookie in postman which is what made the authorization fail. Now at last both postman and the app fail to authoriza which feels oike progress